One hibernate entity for multiple tables of similar structure across different instaces of snowflake database
I am building Spring Boot 3 application that needs to extract data from client databases. For now, there are 18 client databases (the count is most likely to increase). All are snowflake databases. future databases will also be Snowflake. The number of tables and views will also be the same eventually including their structure.
I am going to deploy multiple instances of my Spring Boot 3 application. There will be 2 instances for each database. The idea is to just read the data from these databases.
However, currently, some of the table and view names are slightly different even though the underlying schema is the same across different client databases.
Is there any way I can reuse the same hibernate entity instead of creating a duplicate one for each database? is there a way I can replace the table/view name based on the profile?
